# Google Analytics: how to toggle on "Link Apps From Google Play"

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play, google-play-services

I have an android app which is on Play Store. And I have different campaign URLs (of different medium, created using URL builder) which points my app at Play Store.

On Google Play Console there is link which tell us to set the Link Google Analytics.

Saying "Are you already using Google Analytics in your app?
Connect your Analytics account with the Developer Console to see user engagement data all in one convenient place.
[Link Google Analytics and the Developer Console](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2956981)"

I followed the steps and I created the account (Mobile App) at Google Analytics. I stopped at "Get Google Play Developer Console Data" - "Link Apps From Google Play" under Account->Property->Property Settings. I am unable to toggle button On. Its disable. Not sure why it is disabled.

Can some one please tell me, how to toggle? Basically I need to track the Campaign URLs. Also how do I link my android app to Google Analytics?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you get any answer ? i am stuck at same point

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use the same Google account for both, then you cannot toggle "on"

Hope this helps.

Comment: what if you add the account used for Google Play as a non-admin with access to a Google Analytics property? Otherwise this is a big miss by Google